# Non-linear regression simulation

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, simulation

I have a sequence of data:

`data = {{20, 291}, {21, 440}, {22, 571}, {23, 830}, {24, 1287}, {25, 1975}, {26, 2744}, {27, 4515}, {28, 5974}, {29, 7711}};`

The data is in the exponential form `x1 Exp[x2 t] - x3`. For some reason, I would like to transform the data to the linear form `log (CR(t) + x3)` first, and then transform it back to the exponential form. I would like to find the best value of `x3` that can give me the best simulation. The ideal value for `x3` should be around 1.1. Is there any way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Try this `logdata=Map[{#[[1]],Log[#[[2]]]}&,data]; sol=FindFit[logdata,m*x+b,{m,b},x]; ef=E^(m*x+b)/.sol; Show[ListPlot[data],Plot[ef,{x,20,29}]]` and see how close that is to what you want. If it isn't right then please explain what I've misunderstood and need to change.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, when I wrote `sol = FindFit[logdata, m*x + b, {m, b}, x];`, it didn't work and gave me an error message saying that 0.2 is not a valid variable. I'm also confused about why 0.2 is showing up.

Comment: @yixjia Restart your kernel and try again!

Comment: Oh, I guess the problem is with my edition of Mathematica. When I tried it online, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @yixjia Everyone wants Mathematica to be FAST! So Mathematica remembers `x=0.2` and will use that each time you enter `x` again. And it does this for bigger expressions. You can tell Mathematica to forget by doing `x=.;` or by restarting Mathematica or by looking up how to use `Clear` or `ClearAll`  Different subject. The value for `b` I found was not near 1.1. Is the value I found good? Or should the calculation be different to get closer to 1.1?  Note in Mathematica `Log` is "natural log"

Comment: What is the definition of `CR` ?

Comment: @Bill Thank you for your explanation! The value is good enough. If we express `Exp[-1.8664 + 0.376405t] - x3` in the form of `x1 Exp[x2 t] - x3`, we can obtain `x1≈0.15; x2≈0.37; x3≈1.1;`